# Firebase GA4 iOS and Android Sessions and Duration discrepancies

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics-4

Migrated our iOS and Android Apps to native and using Firebase SDK but since this time our average session duration on Android has gone from 1.5 minutes to 29 minutes.

At the same time our iOS sessions have gone way up.

Seems like an issue with session timeout not working on Android and maybe timing out too fast on iOS.

Looking for a starting point or if this is some new GA4/Firebase bug.